# java float conversion to string giving different result

Tags: java, floating-point, floating-point-conversion

why below java code prints different value (decimal part) of same float variable?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    float f = 2001797.11f;
    System.out.println(String.format("%013.2f", f));
    System.out.println(Float.toString(f));
    System.out.println(String.format("%018.5f", f));
}
```

Output:

```
0002001797.13
2001797.1
000002001797.12500
```

Comment: I thinks it may be some rounding off behind the screen but want to know why this behavior when i am just trying to print the same variable. None of them giving the actual value

Comment: `2001797.11` is too large to be represented precisely to float precision

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The confusion stems from the line `float f = 2001797.11f;`. The closest `float` to the mathematical value `"2001797.11"` is actually `2001797.125`. You can see this by doing

```
System.out.println(new BigDecimal(2001797.11f));
```

So, `f` is actually `2001797.125` and the 2 uses of `String.format` have rounded correctly.

So why doesn't `Float.toString(f)` produce `"2001797.125"`? It's because `Float.toString` only displays enough decimal places in order to distinguish the value from other `float`s. In this case, just displaying the `1` after the decimal place is enough.

Answer (score 2):

You must consider that `float` and `double` types handle *floating point* numbers: This means that they have to distribute its 32 or 64 bits between the integer and the decimal part.

And so: The most digits in the integer part, the most bits will be dedicated to them, and the less bits to the decimal part. So, the decimal part will be *less accurate*.

The problem you are suffering comes from two facts:

- Too much digits in the integer part.
- Using float.

If you need more precission (according to the scale of values your program must handle), you should migrate to `double`. And if you want infinite precission, to `BigDecimal`.

Answer (score 0):

`String.format` use explicit formatting rules while 
`Float.toString(float n)` use the algorithm which is described in documentation:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#toString(float)

Comment: so should we call it a bug or feature as per design ?